# Launch a GTK# application from a Linux service

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gtk#

*Environment*:
RHEL 5.7, 64-bit
runlevel 5 
mono 2.6.7

I have a C# console application that is run as a service on startup. From that application's code, it launches two processes that are also C# applications. One is another console app, and one is a GTK application (but is set to not show its GUI window).

Running this main app normally (mono app.exe) works fine. However, when running it as a service, the GTK application crashes at Application.Init() with a "GTK-cannot open display" error message.

That error message is also what we see when we try directly running the GTK app (aka "mono appname.exe") in runlevel 3 (assuming because Application.Init() does something with the window manager that is not there). So does a linux service somehow start in runlevel 3, even though we start the machine in runlevel 5? And if so, is there a way I can force it to run at runlevel 5?

Thank you.

EDIT - more information:
The GTK application is set up so that it can run with or without launching its GUI via a command line parameter. However, we are using Gtk.Application.Run() to start the application from main no matter which way it's running. Gtk.Application.Init() must be called before Gtk.Application.Run(), and it tries to do something with the x server - which obviously causes a problem in runlevel 3. However, our machine will always be started in runlevel 5.

The main app that launches the other two is setup as a service because the overall system it's going on requires it to start as a service at boot time. So, is there a way to run it in a user-interactive mode? (even though they won't actually be interacting with it directly)

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with GTK# so I don't want to postulate on an answer, but it sounds to me the difficulty here is that daemons/background services usually don't run in a user-interactive mode and the processes are run in an isolated scope that does not have an initialized instance of X running. You would have the same problem with trying to run a Windows Form application from a Windows Service not set to run in user interactive mode. Since this is a background service why does it require a GUI? Perhaps the solution is to think about the problem in a different way.

Comment: Either Mono itself or your application has a bug because it is still trying to connect to X server even though you claim it is set not to show its GUI.

Comment: Vlad: yes, in my Main class, Application.Init tries to connect to the X server, and without it I cannot run Application.Run. What we are not doing, is instantiating the GUI window (another class).  Which in theory should be fine, since we can run at runlevel 5.

Comment: TheXenocide: is there a way to set the service to user-interactive mode in linux?

Comment: I'm not familiar with one but there might be; I'm not super familiar with runlevel isolation. I suppose it's all contextual though; something that auto-starts at X login isn't necessarily a service but could do the trick. That said, if your app is capable of running without the GUI and the service is supposed to leverage that, maybe you should move the code you're trying to execute into a shared assembly and have the GUI and the Service both reference it, rather than having the service shell a separate process? Or if there's value in the separate process, you could make a command line app?

Comment: I think the main difficulty with making a user-interactive service is that startup services are executed in an isolated logon that isn't associated with after-the-fact user logons, even if the service is launched under a specific user's credentials and that same user logs into X (which is not likely to always be the case) they are technically still not executing in the same space. Still, don't quote me on this, my expertise isn't in nixy stuff so I could be way off.

Comment: GTK apps wont run without X, Application.Init() will only work if you have the DISPLAY environment variable pointing to a valid X server.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to do this easily without dividing your program into two or more parts.

When started as a service during boot your program will either be running as root or another nominated user. It will not have an associated X session ( X may not have started either ).

When the GTK main loop (via Application.Init) starts it tries to contact the X server which it wont be able to find or if it does may not have permission to use.

You should split your program into a background service and a GUI, cramming the two in the same thing has development drawbacks aswell.

Also, presumably, your service has some sort of client program? Why can your GUI not be a client also and launched separately?